# Cтили не применяются при .header-nav a + a:hover

Tags: html, css, hover

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Хочу задать стили ссылкам при наведении в блоке nav.

Если для этого указывать .header-nav a:hover, то они работают.
Если указывать .header-nav a + a:hover, тогда перестают. А я просто хочу задать стили при наведении всем ссылкам, кроме первой (там логотип).
Вроде бы специфичность этого правила выше, чем у остальных применённых к классу header-nav.
Комбинаторы вообще работают с псевдоклассами? Или проблема в другом?

```css
.header-nav {
  color: #1D253C;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.header-nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

.header-nav li + li {
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.header-nav a + a:hover {
  color: #007188;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #007188;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Logo" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Life insurance</a></li>
    <li class="header-link-why-bello">
      <a href="#">Why Bello</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: А должны? Комбинатор `+` выбирает элемент, который находится непосредственно после указанного элемента, если у них общий родитель.

Comment: А правильно я тебя поняла, что по сути сейчас браузер не понимает после какого элемента а ему начать применять стили?

Comment: Видимо в моей голове сложилось абсолютно неправильное понимание работы комбинатора +.

Comment: абсолютно неправильное, да. у вас `<a>` в `<li>` вообще-то обернуты, вот к ним и надо обращаться было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для наглядности сделал ховер красным. По-факту на `.header-nav:hover` для элемента `a` Вы меняете цвет и другие стили на нужные Вам, а уже для конкретного `a:hover` элемента оставляете цвет который был по-умолчанию.

```css
.header-nav {
  color: #1D253C;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.header-nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

.header-nav li + li {
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.header-nav a {
  color: #007188;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.header-nav:hover a {
  color: red;
}

.header-nav a:hover {
  color: #007188;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Life insurance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Why Bello</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @aliceandcode можете тогда прожать как верный ответ, если он Вам подошел.